# Pass data from one Angular component to another

Tags: javascript, angular

Yes, this has been asked a couple of times - feel free merging the question - but I'm probably a lamer. I have two components in a page which go like this:

```
<post-list></post-list>
<post-detail><post-detail>
```

This is a very straightforward master-detail page. When the user clicks an item on a list in `post-list`, then `post-detail` loads the selected post and displays it.

The question is how do I get a value from `post-list` to `post-detail` to make it react instantly? I assume there should be an Observable in `post-detail` waiting for changes. I also assume it should watch an input property. The question is: can I get a value from `post-list` and send it as an input property to `post-detail`? Can (and should) I route it through the parent component, or should I define a service for this?

Comment: since you mention Observable, can we assume that this is a question about angular2 and has nothing to do with angularjs?

Comment: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#bidirectional-service

Comment: Yes, Angular 2, more exactly Angular 4. Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way of doing is from @Input and @Output decorators. Your parent component should handle whats being passed to and from the child component.

```
<post-list
    (itemSelected)="loadDetails(any)">
</post-list>
<post-detail
    [selectedItem]="any">
<post-detail>
```

**itemSelected** -> is an Output which is an EventEmitter which emits whats being selected from the list component to the parent component.

**loadDetails(any)** -> This is a method in your parent component which handles whats being emitted by list component, Do whats required to what you get from the child.

**selectedItem** -> is an input property in detail component and it could be of any type which should ideally receive whats being structured from loadDetails.

This is just a simple template which could cater your requirement.
But a service could be written to handle this as well.

Answer (score 1):

Since both of your components have a common parent, the simplest way would be to use @Input() and @Output() properties and have the parent play a role of a mediator. I recorded a short video on this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tSXx4NoKEYY

You can also implement master-detail using the Router and Observable. Blogged about it here: https://yakovfain.com/2016/11/20/angular-2-implementing-master-detail-using-router/

Answer (score 1):

> The question is how do I get a value from post-list to post-detail to make it react instantly? I assume there should be an Observable in post-detail waiting for changes. I also assume it should watch an input property. The question is: can I get a value from post-list and send it as an input property to post-detail? Can (and should) I route it through the parent component, or should I define a service for this?

This situation is pretty straightforward - the post-list needs to indicate when an item is selected, and pass that 'selectedItem' information to the post-detail for display.

If I were handling that situation, I would use simple inputs and outputs (i.e. property and event bindings) to pass the information between the components, using the parent component as the mediator of the communication. You are routing it through the parent component - specifically, the post-list is indicating when a post is selected and what that post is, whereas the post-detail is simply displaying whatever post is passed to it.

So, the post-list needs an @Output EventEmitter property called itemSelect or something else appropriate. The purpose of this property is to notify anyone who cares when an item is selected and what that item is.

**PostListComponent:**

```
export class PostDetailComponent {
   .....
   @Output() postSelect = new EventEmitter();

   // whenever a post is selected, you call this.postSelect.emit(selectedPost)
   // to notify others which post is selected
```

**In the PostDetailComponent:**

```
export class PostDetailComponent {
   .....
   // this is your property binding 
   // used to get data in real time in to the component for display
  @Input() post;
```

Finally, the parent component needs a post property to receive updates from the post-list and pass those updates to the post-detail.

**ParentComponent**

The ParentComponent simply listens for updates from the PostList, and on receiving them, assigns the substance of the event (the $event value in the template) to its internal post property, which in turn gets pushed to the PostDetail.

```
 @Component({
    .......
    template: `
       <post-list (postSelect)="post = $event"> </post-list>
       <post-detail [post]="post"> </post-detail>
    `
 })
 export class ParentComponent {
     post: any;  // brokers the communication between the two child components
    .......
```

That's how I would the situation.

You can use a service to broker the communication, but that's usually only necessary if the means of communication is complicated or the two components aren't close to each other in the view hierarchy, so it's difficult to get information from one component to the other. But in your case, a service may be overkill.

[See the docs for more info.](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html)

Comment: Thanks. This was exactly what I had in mind, and implemented in the meantime. I was not sure if this is not going against some best practice or any unwritten rule. That's what difficult about Angular, not the logic behind it.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this:

1- inject **$rootScope** to both of your components

2- implement below code to one of them as a data receiver:

```
$rootScope.$on('transferDataEvent', function(data) {

  });
```

3- and for another call below code as a data sender

```
$rootScope.$emit('transferDataEvent', data); // send data
```

**$on** makes a listener and
 **$emit** dispatches the event upwards through the scope hierarchy

Comment: That's AngularJS, not Angular, but thanks anyway. Unfortunately there's no Angular 4 tag for questions yet.

Answer (score 0):

An easier approach to your problem is to use template reference variables: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#ref-vars

I suggest that, because your components are siblings, ie. share the same parent.

you can reference `post-list` component on the template this way:

look at this plnkr I set up: https://plnkr.co/edit/C7kjlaZItfn0sE12HNMO?p=preview

here is the code:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2>Hello {{name}}</h2>
      <post-list #postList></post-list>
      <post-detail [text]="postList?.chosen?.detail"></post-detail>
    </div>
  `,
})
export class App {
  name:string;
  constructor() {
    this.name = `Angular! v${VERSION.full}`
  }
}


@Component({
  selector: 'post-detail',
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2>{{text}}</h2>
    </div>
  `,
})
export class PostDetail {
  @Input() text: string;
  constructor() {
  }
}


@Component({
  selector: 'post-list',
  template: `
    <div>
      <ul>
        <li *ngFor="let post of posts; let i = index">
        <button (click)="chosen = posts[i]">{{post.title}}</button>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  `,
})
export class PostList {
  chosen: any;
  posts: [] =
  [
    { title:"post 1", detail:"post one detail" },
    { title:"post 2", detail:"post two detail" },
    { title:"post 3", detail:"post three detail" },
  ] 
  constructor() {
  }
}
```